# Pyright Language Server with Neovim not loading new files

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

When I am creating a new file in neovim (without closing the neovim instance), I am unable to import the variables from those files (import the new file as a module) in other files of my project unless I restart my neovim. What could be wrong with the noevim LSP configuration? I have basic LSP configured as follows:

```
lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  -- see :help lsp-zero-keybindings
  -- to learn the available actions
  lsp_zero.default_keymaps({buffer = bufnr})
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "K", function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vws", function() vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vd", function() vim.diagnostic.open_float() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_next() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_prev() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vca", function() vim.lsp.buf.code_action() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrr", function() vim.lsp.buf.references() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrn", function() vim.lsp.buf.rename() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-h>", function() vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() end, opts)
end)

require('lspconfig').tsserver.setup({})
require('lspconfig').rust_analyzer.setup({})
require'lspconfig'.pyright.setup{}
require'lspconfig'.texlab.setup{}
require'lspconfig'.gopls.setup{}
```